# How can I use firstWhereOrNull with a map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I use firstWhereOrNull with maps in Flutter?

In other words, how can I do this:

```
final myVariable1 = myList.firstWhereOrNull(
        (myVariable2) =>
            !myList.containsValue(myVariable2));
```

Instead of using a list (myList), I'd like to do the same with a map (Map<String,int>).

```
Map<String,int> myMap = {};
myMap("stuff1") = 1;
myMap("stuff2") = 2;
myMap("stuff3") = 3;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your map variable?

Comment: I just added it to my question. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you like to check null value based on keys?

Comment: `Map<String, int>` allows neither nullable keys nor values.  A `Map` itself isn't an `Iterable` (so therefore can't use `firstWhere` or `firstWhereOrNull` directly), but you can get `Iterable`s from it (e.g. via its [`keys`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/keys.html), [`values`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/values.html), or [`entries`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/entries.html) properties).  We can't answer your question without you specifying what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such `firstWhereOrNull` method for Maps, but you can easily come up with one using extension methods:

```dart
extension ExtendedMap on Map {
  /// The first entry satisfying test, or null if there are none.
  MapEntry? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(MapEntry entry) test) {
    for (var entry in this.entries) {
      if (test(entry)) return entry;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```dart
final map = <String, int>{
  'stuff1': 1,
  'stuff2': 2,
  'stuff3': 3,
};

final test = map.firstWhereOrNull((entry) => entry.value == 2);

print(test); // Prints MapEntry(stuff2: 2)

final nullTest = map.firstWhereOrNull((entry) => entry.key == "stuff5");

print(nullTest); // Prints null
```

Comment: I use this, but i found that i can't use conditional operator like > or <. I can only use ==

Comment: Why can't you use conditional operators? Try this: `final test = map.firstWhereOrNull((entry) => entry.value > 1 || entry.value < 2);` It will return the first entry even though the second one meets the condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, I created this implementation, I don't think it's the most optimized, also because it was necessary to use the cast since because of the sound null safety, it's not possible to return any value. But it works for you.

```dart
var myMap = {"key1": "value", "key2": 3};

var result = myMap.entries
  .cast<dynamic>()
  .firstWhere((e) => e.key == "key", orElse: () => null);

print(result);
```

I hope this helps in some way!